# workflow versioning

Tags: workflow, state-machine

I have a sharepoint project and it contains 5 state machine workflows. I had deployed these workflows through VS and they are working as expected. Now here comes the tricky part versioning for these workflows(keeping future changes in these workflows in mind). What are the best practices to be followed for sharepoint state machine workflow versioning for my scenario?. Any ideas, links and tutorials is very much appreciated.

I had already followed the link by Phil but it is not working for me.
http://blog.philwicklund.com/fff/2010/06/sharepoint-workflow-versioning-with-visual-studio-2010.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following links were really helpful and solved by requirement.

http://sharepoint497.blogspot.in/2012/09/upgrading-or-redeploying-sharepoint.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yardman/archive/2010/04/14/versioning-a-visual-studio-sharepoint-workflow.aspx

Thanks
K.Anantha rengan